# How to match string pattern in groovy if condition

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want to set Build_RELEASE based on value of stream. Suppose if STREAM contains value with "release" it should be def as BUILD_RELEASE="1" else "0"

```
if ("${STREAM}" == "release-*"){
def BUILD_RELEASE="1"
}else {
def BUILD_RELEASE="0"
}
```

While testing the above code snippet I gave STREAM as release-V1 but the BUILD_RELEASE value is  taken as null . How to modify the if condition so that it can match for pattern with release

Comment: What is the type of STREAM variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare variables inside an `if` block, and to compare things with wildcards, you need to use a Regular Expression and the matching operator `==~`

```
​def BUILD_RELEASE = ​​STREAM ==~ 'release-.*' ? '1' : '0'
```

Should give you what you want.

If you're just checking the start of a String, `startsWith` will be quicker (and easier for others to understand)

```
​def BUILD_RELEASE = ​​STREAM.startsWith('release-') ? '1' : '0'
```